# How to quickly delete all build definition?

Tags: tfs, build-definition

In `Build` page in `Team Explorer`, we have a list of build definition and when select them all, the delete command is disabled.

Selecting only one enable us to delete it.

Is there other places where we can quickly clear all the build definition?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To Deletion of the build, The documentation is here have a look for deletion
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475877(v=vs.100).aspx#deletebuild

just goto "**To delete a completed build**" this section and read

**Updated:** (I thought you were asking for build deletion)

Here I found a tool called Team Project Manager, It allows you to automates various tasks as they mentioned. you can try this

http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/

[image]

Comment: I think he was asking about deleting build definitions, not deleting completed builds.

Comment: I'm able to use this tool to do a number of bulk operations against our TFS instance.  I think the OP was asking about deleting build definitions.  TFS requires you to delete any completed builds for that definition before you can delete the definition itself.  The tool has a handy checkbox that will do both steps for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free tool called the Community TFS Build Manager that allows bulk operations on Build Definitions (including Delete).  You can find the 2013 version here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f